# 'Ghost' data corrupting hyperlink

Tags: excel

I have a column of external hyperlink, the problem is the links don't work because some wrong data remained after a copy&paste.

[image]

as you can see here my cell only shows the hyperlink but when I hover it I can see the wrong data being used by excel.

Is there a way to clear these cells from this 'ghost' content and make excel use the cell's value as the hyperlink ?

Also is there a name for all this content being used but not shown ? Knowing this would help my google searches.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: right click on the cell > edit Hyperlink: there you will see the *Display Text* (which you can see in the cell) and the *address* (which is the link shown in the popup). You would need VBA to clean the links, ie. update the address with the display text

Comment: Thank you but as I have many many cells I was looking for a way to apply that to the whole column.

Comment: As said: you will need VBA for that

Comment: My response was posted before your edit, thank you for pointing me in that direction I will look up VBA